# Textual ways to represent percentage without numbers?

Tags: text, data-visualisation

I am making an application which reminds users to take breaks at intervals (the user can set the interval). I’d like to give the user an idea of how much time is left until the break, but not give the exact number of minutes. To achieve this, I use a progress bar in the main window to display the amount of time left until taking a break

**I'm now looking for a textual way to represent what I'm displaying in the progress bar**, because I need to put the same information in a menu in the system tray (where I can only show text)

### My thinking so far

#### Percentage

I could use percentage, but I’d like to find a way where the user sees some graphics instead of numbers

#### Progress as period characters

I’ve also been thinking of using something like this:

[image: progress]

(the percentage in parenthesis would not be displayed)

The problem with this is that to work well it assumes that the font is monospaced, and this is something I cannot control unfortunately.

Comment: But why not just show numbers if text is the only thing you can use? A nice large visual ticker is going to look more attractive than your current idea.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: Thank you for the question, i've been thinking about this as well, one thing i'm worried about is that people will be confused when seeing the percentage numbers and think "why isn't the number of minutes shown"? (the reason i don't want numbers is that i'd like to avoid focusing the users attention on a specific number of minutes remaining until the next break)

Comment: But wouldn't a simple '%' behind the number fix that? I agree with Webster's answer but I'm not sure if that's possible within your app.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: Unfortunately i cannot do what Webster suggests, but yes i agree this would be a good solution otherwise. About the percentage sign: I'd like to avoid using numbers at all (even with a percentage sign behind the numbers) and would like to find a way to display time left/passed "in a graphical way but with text" in a manner of speaking

Comment: This will only work for LTR languages according to cognitive science for linear (spatial) representation for flow of time. See link for abstract: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21564254

Comment: You'll need something (animation) to indicate that the process is in progress and hasn't crashed or become inactive, hung-up, and unresponsive.

Comment: You need text and have explained why. Fine. Also it has to be monospaced, fine. Tell us which font it is and we (and you) can look what glyph looks best to make a pseudo-progressbar. For example elipsis (three dots) might look better than just a period in monospaced; it really depends on what font is being used (or whether you have no influence). When you say "making an application", what is the context, Android?

Comment: I voted to close this. It's really too broad and ultimately any suggestions would be subjective opinion,  not definitive solutions. There are a million different ways to use text glyphs to indicate progression or declination.. simply start with 4/8 glyphs then remove/add a glyph or two as values increase/decrease.  —>  —>  —>  To show it "active" you could blink the glphs or have colors rotate subtly.

Comment: Scott, if you know millions of ways to solve this, please write one good answer for sunyata (not forgetting the monospace complication) and he will be happy. Much better than closing. We often need working solutions, not definitve solutions. In a context like graphicdesign, you could tag many questions and answers as subjective, because this is not mathematics. I cannot vote here, but in my office I also collect several ideas before I commit to two or three drafts and then to one graphic solution; nothing wrong with such an approach.

Comment: @MartinZaske I can respect that. But StackExchange isn't a forum for "collecting ideas". It strives for *definitive* answers. While there is *some* leeway here due to the subjectiveness of art, I feel overly broad, questions merely asking for *pure* opinion are too broad to be effectively answered. You are free to disagree, obviously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your progress bar idea will work, but you need to find two characters with the same width: one filled, one blank.

There are sites, like [this one](https://changaco.oy.lc/unicode-progress-bars/), that may give you some ideas for what characters you could use.

You can also just look at Unicode character lists and find a pair yourself (this may take some trial and error). On the Wikipedia pages for [geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes) and [block elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) I found some symbols that work [at least on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9gJv.png):

---

**Dots `&#9679;` and `&#9675;`**:

○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○ ○
● ● ● ● ● ○ ○ ○ ○ ○
● ● ● ● ● ● ● ● ● ●

---

**Emoji squares `&#9725;` and `&#9726;`**:

◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️
◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️◽️◽️◽️◽️◽️
◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️◾️

---

**Shaded blocks `&#9617;` and `&#9619;`**:

░░░░░░░░░░
▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░
▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓

Answer (score 0):

That can be shown with a progress bar. Everyone understands what a rectangle getting filled from the left means.

You could do a rotating, clock style counter as well, 1 full rotation of the hand is 100%.

There are various meters, bars and graphs that show a proportional quantity or time.

The theme​ usually is that the shape is being filled. It's a counter and there are many possibilities.

Comment: Progress bars must flow in the same direction as the language being used to be effective according to cognitive science. Link in comments to original post.